# ReactJS Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <li>

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I don't get it react throws me this error: `Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <li>` Because everything is closed well and it is only when I have multiple `li` elements

```
 render() {
        return (
          <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
            <ul className="nav sidebar-nav">
              <li>
                  <a href="#" className="active">
                    <i className="fa fa-home"></i>Home
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a className="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">
                  <i className="fa fa-user"></i> About me<i className="fa fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                </a>
              <li>
            </ul>
          </nav>     
        );
      }
```

Can anybody help me out on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a slash in the second closing `li`:

```
  <li>
    <a className="collapsible-header waves-effect arrow-r">
      <i className="fa fa-user"></i> About me<i className="fa fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Comment: Lol thanks you'r right sometimes you are not noticing it because you are into it